# Alternative to html offsetTop

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom

I had used offsetTop in my solution as follows.

```
public getOffsetTop = element => {
       let offsetTop = 0;
       while (element) {
         offsetTop += element.offsetTop;
         element = element.offsetParent;
       }
    return offsetTop;
  };

const field = document.getElementById("error");
const totalOffsetTop = this.getOffsetTop(field);

window.scrollTo({
        top: totalOffsetTop,
        behavior: "smooth"
      });
```

This works smoothly. Whenever there is an error, i am able to scroll back automatically to the error field. 
However, here is the real issue. offsetTop is experimental and should not be used in production. https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-api_htmlelement_offsettop

I tried using getBoundingClientRect().top but it doesnot scroll back to the error field. Can anyone suggest a better alternative ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so it helps someone, i tried this and it worked.

```
public getOffsetTop = element => {
      const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
      const scrollTop =
        window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
      return rect.top + scrollTop;
  };
```

Answer (score 3):

What about [Element.scrollIntoView()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)?

You could just:

```js
document.getElementById("error").scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
```